# Charge Apple magic mouse 2 using iPhone lightning Qi wireless charger

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, charger

Can I charge Apple magic mouse 2 using iPhone lightning Qi wireless charger adapter and pad? It seams like it should work in theory, but I wonder if there is some kind of compatibility or feature with the mouse that would prevent this.

More info: Sorry, for lack of details, looking to use something like these:

```
https://www.amazon.com/Apple-Receiver-iPhone-Wireless-Charger/dp/B01MT6150G/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1501775730&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=qi+iphone+receiver.&psc=1

https://www.amazon.com/SurgeDisk-Wireless-Charging-Sleep-Friendly-Universal/dp/B01HYLST9Q/ref=sr_1_9?s=wireless&ie=UTF8&qid=1501775763&sr=1-9&keywords=qi+charger
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/293309/edit) your question to include details of what iPhone lightning Qi wireless charger adapter and pad you're actually referring to? Please note though, if you're referring to pre-release Apple hardware then your question will be off-topic on this site until it is released.

Comment: Sorry for lack of details, I think these should be compatible with the current model magic mouse 2.